# Unexpected end of line

Tags: shell

```
mysqldump -u $dbUsername --password=$dbPassword --databases $db | gzip > ${dbBackup}/${db}-${date}.sql.gz
if [ echo $? -ne 0 ]; then
  mail -s "Backup mysql cron job $0 failed" $MAIL_TO <<EOF


 EOF
```

Error after executing the script - Unexpected end of line

Comment: Why there are two EOF present?

Answer (score 1):

The fi terminating the if statement was missing:

```
mysqldump -u $dbUsername --password=$dbPassword --databases $db | gzip > ${dbBackup}/${db}-${date}.sql.gz
if [ echo $? -ne 0 ]; then
  mail -s "Backup mysql cron job $0 failed" $MAIL_TO <<EOF
 EOF
fi
^^^
```